# How to debug c# project on Mono using comand line using Windows os

Tags: c#, mono, command, line, exe

I downloaded Mono from the oficial website, I added path using CMD: `setx path "%path%;C:\Programs\Mono\bin"` and then I opened Mono to see comands. 
I wrote a code using notepad to test it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    }
}
```

I named it into **mis.cs** and now I want to debug it!
I wrote `cd C:/Users...` and than I tried first `mono mis.cs` but said that `Cannot open assembly 'mis.cs': File does not contain a valid CIL image.` And than I wrote `mono --debug mis.cs` and said the same. I tried also with 'mono --debug mis.cs -o mis.exe' and same.
What should I do? I don't want to use Microsoft VS. I want to use the old method.

Comment: Take a look at their docs...-> https://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/

Comment: Also compiling with mono -> https://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/linux/